# How can I force Jquery animations to occur when the window is not focused

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, animation, fadein

Okay,
So I am building an ajax based game. Anyway it is multiplayer, connects to a server. It polls the server, getting updates all the time. Anyway the game has different game states, and must animate the GUI based on the game state.

The problem is, however; When the window is not focused, jquery animations queue up and do not render. This means say a user walks away for 5 mins and comes back, a huge queue of obsolete animations start to run through one by one.

So I was wondering if there is any way to force jquery animations to run when they are called and not wait for a focused window?

For further information on why this happens, read Additional Notes, in the jquery documentation here http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

Cheers, Josh

Comment: I think that's a feature of the browser that helps to reduce memory footprint or resource usage.  You might not be able to fix that inside of page code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the animations, you could add onfocus event on the body element that gets the animation queue by calling `.queue()` and if it's longer than one element, you could call `.clearQueue()`. Of course you'd have to be careful not to mess up the layout, since it removes all the animations.

Also you could try doing `jQuery.fx.off = true` if the list is longer than one element. This should set the duration of all animations to 0, which should result in all of the queued animations being finished instantly, and to enable animations once again, set the value to false. However, since I haven't tried it myself, I'm not sure if it sets the duration only on the animations that haven't yet been run (already in a queue) or on only those that haven't yet been added to a queue. If the latter case is true, you could loop through the queue and set each duration to 0 manually.

Comment: I have tried :
 
 $(window).focus(function(){jQuery.fx.off = false;});
 
 
 $(window).blur(function(){jQuery.fx.off = true;});
 
 will post back if it keeps working.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Zanfa's answer - you could use the focus event, but you could also use it in combination with the blur event.

So rather than trying to clean everything up on focus, you could use the blur event to cleanly pause the game, stop any animations and then later use the focus to get things going again.