# Run animation when element is visible on screen

Tags: jquery, visible

I've a little progress bars script. It works fine but runs on page load. I want to run animation when bars are visible on screen (it should work too if progress bars would be in tabs). How may I get this?

Here's script:

```
setTimeout(function(){

    $('.skill-bar .skill-bar-content').each(function() {
        var me = $(this);
        var perc = me.attr("data-percentage");

        var current_perc = 0;

        var progress = setInterval(function() {
            if (current_perc>=perc) {
                clearInterval(progress);
            } else {
                current_perc +=1;
                me.css('width', (current_perc)+'%');
            }

            me.text((current_perc)+'%');

        }, 10);

    });

},10);
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fUyYL/

Comment: i think this answer will resolve your issue:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6689793/how-can-i-force-jquery-animations-to-occur-when-the-window-is-not-focused

Comment: It doesn't work as I want to be serious so I'd try other solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/fUyYL/1/

```
var ele = $('#skill-bars');
if( ele.is(':visible') ) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: @eXorcist because element's css got `display:none`, when removed http://jsfiddle.net/fUyYL/2/

Comment: animation work without scrolling, wait few seconds and scroll and you will see animation finished, add more pixels for top margin , wait and then scroll